# Using flowfram for creating several frames in landscape

Tags: flowfram

How can I create the following frames in landscape, using `flowfram` package?

The dashed lines should not be visible in the output; they are just drawn here to make the boundary of the frames clear.

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit too complicated for the predefined layouts, but it's also going to be fiddly trying to work out the co-ordinates and dimensions for `\newflowframe`. You might prefer to use a graphical approach with [jpgfdraw](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/). (There's an [example tutorial](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/manual/postertutorial.html) on how to use the application to create flow frames.)

Comment: Hpw does the text flow from one frame to the next? Mark them with numbers so it's clear. Also, what happens in the blank spots? And will this *only* be a single landscape page that requires this layout?

Comment: @Werner: The text does not flow from one frame to another (which frames are you talking about?). Nothing happens in blank spots. Yes, this is only one single landscape page.

Comment: I have just done it.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi would you mind posting your solution as an answer? I'm curious...

Comment: @cgnieder: I just followed Nicola's suggestion. I will post the solution later.